# What causes this exception to be thrown "observer error"?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I only get this error if it is iOS 7 and if I include spcluster custom map (super pin map). Why does this error occur and how do I fix it?

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <MKMapAnnotationManager 0xb355a00> for the key path "coordinate" from <Annotation 0x194c1470> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove an observer related to MKMapView or MKMapAnnotaionManager, for which you have not added any observer in your class?

Comment: I have the same crash on this line: `[self.allAnnotationMapView removeAnnotations:self.allAnnotationMapView.annotations];` Weird...

Comment: I have the same issue while using MSMapClustering.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same issue.

You can solve it by doing this.

1. Create a subclass of MKAnnotation or add the following to your existing subclass.
2. In it, add a variable (this is in Swift but you can interpret this for ObjC as well):

```
    var observers: NSMutableSet! = NSMutableSet()
```

3. Then, add the following methods:

```
    override func addObserver(observer: NSObject, forKeyPath keyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: UnsafeMutablePointer) {
        let observerId : String = "\(observer.hashValue)\(keyPath)"

        self.observers.addObject(observerId)
        super.addObserver(observer, forKeyPath: keyPath, options: options, context: context)
    }

    override func removeObserver(observer: NSObject, forKeyPath keyPath: String) {

        let observerId : String = "\(observer.hashValue)\(keyPath)"

        if (self.observers.containsObject(observerId)) {
            self.observers.removeObject(observerId)
            super.removeObserver(observer, forKeyPath: keyPath)
        }
    }
```

4. Use this subclass with your MKMapView.

For debugging, if you add an "NSLog" statement inside of an **else** block in removeObserver() you can see that occasionally MKMapView (or it's MKAnnotationManager) will randomly decide to remove observation for an MKAnnotation that it's already asked for observation to removed from. This is, according to Apple's own KVO documentation, not to be done.

These overrides "fix" the problem as they keep track (on a per-annotation basis) which observations have already been registered for each annotation, thus allowing you to refuse to de-observe something that has already been de-observed (or never was observed in the first place).

It's kludgy, but they fixed my animation crash. And do so without much performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a common cause of this is that `coordinate` was being observed through a multi-element key path and one of the intermediary keys was modified in a non-KVO-compliant manner. This leaves the internal KVO machinery observing one thing when it thinks it's observing a different thing. Some time later, when a part of the key path is changed in a KVO-compliant manner, this exception is raised.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a more generic issue with this observer error using only classic annotations on a MKMapView.

When trying to execute `mMapView.removeAnnotations(mMapView.annotations)`, I randomly ran into this crash.

Just changing it to :

```
for annotation in mMapView.annotations {
    mMapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation as! MKAnnotation, animated: false)
    mMapView.removeAnnotation(annotation as! MKAnnotation)
}
```

solved my problem.

I can relate it to @Aurelien Porte 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You (or whoever developed that component) is trying to remove `MKMapAnnotationManager` as an observer of `Annotation` (for the key path `coordinate`), by calling `removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:`. However `MKMapAnnotationManager` is not registered as an observer, hence the crash.

The fix is to ensure the calls to `addObserver`/`removeObserver` are always balanced.

Without further details it's all that can be said.

As an extra reference, here's a relevant quote from this [nice blog article about KVO](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/):

> Perhaps the most profound annoyance about KVO is that if you make a call to –`removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:` when the object is not registered as an observer (whether because it was already unregistered or not registered in the first place), it throws an exception. The kicker is that there's not built-in way to even check if an object is registered!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such error when using some code provided by apple documentation for clustering MKMapView annotations. It can be found in sample project PhotoMap.

My problem was that the parent view and MKMapView was deallocated before the animation was finished. The animation was animating the annotation coordinates ( was moving the annotations on the map)

```
for (MyMKAnnotation *annotation in filteredAnnotationsInBucket) {
    // give all the other annotations a reference to the one which is representing them
    annotation.clusterAnnotation = annotationForGrid;
    annotation.containedAnnotations = nil;

    // remove annotations which we've decided to cluster
    if ([visibleAnnotationsInBucket containsObject:annotation]) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D actualCoordinate = annotation.coordinate;

        // This is the flag that I added to disable/enable animation
        if (animateMarkerClustering) {

            // This animation is not finished properly before the annotationViews
            // animation gets finished
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                annotation.coordinate = annotation.clusterAnnotation.coordinate;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                annotation.coordinate = actualCoordinate;
                [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
            }];

        } else {
            annotation.coordinate = actualCoordinate;
            [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the animation on `[self.view removeAllAnimations]`

and

```
if (_mapView.annotations.count > 0){
    NSArray *annotations =_mapView.annotations;

    for(int i=0;i<annotations.count;i++){
        id <MKAnnotation> annotation = annotations[i];

        [[_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation].layer removeAllAnimations];
        [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    //[_mapView removeAnnotations:_mapView.annotations];
}
```

I have achieved nothing.

For the time being i set `animateMarkerClustering=NO` to disable the annotation animations, and that works. No error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on the question but I solved my exact same case with this answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31231307/2248650

Also like slava I am using Apple's sample project PhotoMap as a base for my implementation but I have also ported it to Swift. I also have subclassed MKAnnotation and to enable its coordinate animations like in sample, I had to set dynamic keyword to coordinate:

```
dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
```

And now, like presented, when I deselect annotations before removing them like this

```
for annotation in allAnnotationsMapView.annotations {
    allAnnotationsMapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
    allAnnotationsMapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

I don't encounter the exception anymore.

Answer (score 0):

subclass of XKAnnotation

change

```
func setCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.willChangeValue(forKey: "coordinate")
    self.setValue(coordinate, forKey: "coordinate")
    self.didChangeValue(forKey: "coordinate")
}
```

to

```
func setCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.setValue(coordinate, forKey: "coordinate")
}
```